# CASE statement is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to SELECT data from my MySQL database. If the data is available my database needs to respond with a symbol. If there is no data in the record, my database should respond an empty record (without a symbol).

I am using the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT price1
    CASE 
        WHEN price1 IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT('€ ', price1)
    END as price1 
FROM pricelist 
WHERE id=1
```

When I run this SQL statement, I get a error.

Does someone know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: What error are you getting? Please post the error message.

Comment: Missing comma before case.

Comment: Besides, that's a case expression, not a case statement...

Comment: (as an aside) The value of `price1` is selected and then immediately overwritten by the CASE result.

Comment: @Martin, not overwritten, two different result-set columns.

Comment: @jarlh sorry can you explain that? There is a select that chooses the `price1` and then there is a CASE which takes it's result `as price1` , so the first selection is overwritten by the second as the output fetched is named as `price1` in both instances.

Comment: @Martin, no, the result-set will contain two columns, the original value, and the case expression's output. Perhaps some above layer will run into problems?

Comment: @jarlh (from a PHP background) I see that the output would then have two columns in the output array both with keys `price1`. Sorry but this has confused me....

Answer (score 3):

This is a typo, you are missing a comma - `,` after `price1` .

Other then that, I changed your new column name from `price1` to `new_price1`, since it doesn't make a lot of sense to select two columns with the same name(could cause some trouble especially if you'll want to filter by one of them)

```
SELECT price1,
    CASE 
        WHEN price1 IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT('€ ', price1)
    END as new_price1 
FROM pricelist 
WHERE id=1
```

Other option is that you didn't meant to select `price1` , so:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN price1 IS NOT NULL
             THEN CONCAT('€ ', price1)
        END as new_price1 
FROM pricelist 
WHERE id=1
```

Comment: I am getting two records. One with symbol and one without a symbol

Comment: Everything is explained mate @John , no problem.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, if you keep the both columns, you need a comma (`,`) between them but I think you wanted to  change `price1`'s value.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN price1 IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT('€ ', price1)
        ELSE '' --or null or....
    END as price1 
FROM pricelist 
WHERE id=1
```